# How to make shadow softer?

Tags: graphics, raytracing

[my result , but the shadow is so hard.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMIPc.jpg)

```
for (SceneLight* light : scene->lights)
{
    Vector3D dir_to_light;
    float dist_to_light;
    float pdf;
    int num_light_samples = light->is_delta_light() ? 1 : ns_area_light;
    double scale = 1.0 / num_light_samples;
    for (int i = 0; i < num_light_samples; i++) {
        Spectrum light_L = light->sample_L(hit_p, &dir_to_light, &dist_to_light, &pdf);
        Vector3D w_in = w2o * dir_to_light;
        double cos_theta = std::max(0.0, w_in[2]);
        Spectrum f = isect.bsdf->f(w_out, w_in);
        Ray shadow_ray(hit_p + EPS_D * dir_to_light, dir_to_light, dist_to_light - (EPS_D * dir_to_light).norm(), 0);
        if (!bvh->intersect(shadow_ray))
        {
            L_out += (f * light_L * (cos_theta * scale / pdf));
        }

    }
}
```

**
abolve is my some code and render result. The shadow looks so hard.If i want to make the shadow softer, What can I do? I am writing path tracing.
Thanks.**

Comment: It seems that you are using a point light source. As a first measure, you can split that source in four points (or more). The cast shadows will partly overlap and create penumbra.

Comment: Thanks. I solved it.

Comment: Would be fair to tell how you solved.

Comment: It liked that you said.I sampled from a point light.Now I sample from a area light randomly.And it is ok.